# Is SVG-Based UI an available and / or viable option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I've noticed that SVG graphics seem to be the only option if I want to generate UI components that have curved sides without 90 or 45° angles. For example if I want a menu that looks like this:

http://puu.sh/iLjrq/89724cab83.png

You'd have to do all this with d3.js:

```js
var data = [
  {
    weight: 1,
    label: "Home"
  },
  {
    weight: 1,
    label: "Gallery"
  },
  {
    weight: 1,
    label: "Articles"
  },
  {
    weight: 1,
    label: "Author"  
  }
];

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function (datum) {
    return datum.weight;
  })
  .startAngle(Math.PI * 1 / 2)
  .endAngle(Math.PI * 3 / 2);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(200)
  .innerRadius(140);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr({
      width: 404,
      height: 204
    })
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(202,2)");

var g = svg.selectAll("g > g")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc);

g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function (g) {
    var angle = (g.startAngle + g.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI;
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(g) + ") rotate(" + ((angle + 90) % 180 - 90) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", ".25em")
  .text(function (g) {
    return g.data.label;
  });

$("svg").on("click", ".arc", function (event) {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.arc {
  fill: rgb(128,128,255);
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arc:hover {
  fill: rgb(220,220,100);
}

.arc:active {
  fill: rgb(255,255,128);
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```

My point is, there seem to be a lot of styles that pure HTML and CSS cannot achieve to my knowledge, and must be polyfilled using SVG graphics.

My question is, is there a pure HTML alternative to achieve a user interface like this, or perhaps a more appropriate way to approach generating this that "feels" more like using just JavaScript and CSS like normal HTML? This feels overly difficult to achieve given the currently existing APIs and libraries available, unless there's something I've overlooked.

Comment: For that menu SVG might be the best bet. Although it probably could be done, the css would probably be very complex with a bunch of transforms (see [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/) explanation) because the web is made of squares lol. Vector graphics may make more sense. There are also many other SVG libs out there

Comment: The HTML5 canvas maybe? But the code would probably be just as complicated, and I don't know how straightforward the mouse event interface is (I made a test version of a game using canvas, and noticed some strange behaviour, e.g. after iPads change orientation). But you would be using HTML, CSS and JS only.

Comment: Canvas is not a good route, in my opinion. Yes, drawing things in canvas may be easier but it is not event-friendly, since rendered components in a canvas are not distinct elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to achieve this using CSS transforms, though that wouldn't render simple code. [This would be an example of that](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index.html#).

Comment: Well this is a step towards what I'd like. At least the JavaScript would be less focused on structure and style, and more focused on behavior. After all, CSS is meant to determine style, so something like this would be expected to be complicated.

Comment: I was hoping for more answers on other possibilities before I selected one as correct but this question seems to lack activity, so sorry for the delay.